# Comma after "Why" in "Why thank you."

Tags: punctuation

Joe said, "You're awesome."

"Why thank you," Mel replied.

Should there be a comma after "Why"?

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1798/what-is-the-purpose-of-using-the-word-why-in-why-thank-you

Comment: Read that question and there should be a comma, yes.

Answer (score 1):

"Why" works here as an interjection to express mild surprise. When interjections are at the start of a sentence, [they can be followed by a comma or an exclamation mark.](http://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/commas_after_interjections.htm)

Comment: Conversely, if that punctuation is omitted it would read like a single clause of "why thank you" which could be interpreted as "why should I thank you?".

Comment: They can be.  But should they?  (I think yes.  Your answer doesn't take a stand, as far as I can tell.)