# Why, thank you........not correct

Tags: word-usage

Let's forget how it is used or what it might imply , because why , is why? (?)
Regardless am I not correct." Why, thank you" makes little sense to use unless you are asking why someone is thanking you. let's keep it real , I don't think there is another language that uses such , so  commonly.It is not correct....it makes no sense.  Am i the only one here that feels this way?

Answer (score 0):

The word **Why** has multiple meanings. Specifically **Why** is being used as an interjection in this case. While you are probably interpreting it as an adverb.

[What is the purpose of using the word "why" in "why, thank you"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1798/what-is-the-purpose-of-using-the-word-why-in-why-thank-you)